# Get list of background windows.

Tags: c#, wpf

What would be the best method to retrieve a reference of each window located in the background in reference to another window? 
I want to apply a blur animation to every window except one that has IsTopMost set to true. My goal is to focus attention on a tool window that displays updates on a long running process. I currently have a static class that holds a reference to each open window to prevent multiple instances from running. I could use that; however, I want to make this code reusable in other apps.

Comment: Are you talking about windows that you create yourself or all windows in Windows?

Comment: I am talking about windows in my application. Not necessarily all OS windows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your own list, there is `Application.Current.Windows`.